# Prove that $x$ has order $5$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

let $ x \in G$ such that $(a^{-1})*(x^2)*(a) = x^3$ for some self inverse $a.$ Prove that $x$ has order $5.$

I don't know how to start this proof. Seems really difficult.

Comment: May we assume that $x$ is not the identity of the (I assume) group $G$?  If not, $x$ being the identity (order $1$) is a counterexample.

Comment: If $a$ is self-inverse then $a^2=1$ and $a^{-1}=a$ which should help. You need to assume $x\neq 1$, and this implies that $a$ does not commute with $x$.

Comment: From this we have $\langle x \rangle \rtimes_\varphi \langle a \rangle \cong D_{10}$, where $\varphi:\langle a \rangle\rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(\langle x \rangle)$ is the map defined by $\varphi(a)(x)=x^{-1}$; so we were really working in $D_{10}$ all along.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$a^{-1}x^2a=x^3 \implies a^{-1}x^4a=x^6 \implies a^{-1}x^6a=x^9$ but $x^6=x^3x^3=(a^{-1}x^2a)(a^{-1}x^2a)=a^{-1}x^4a \implies a^{-1}(a^{-1}x^4a)a=x^9 \implies a^{-1}a^{-1}x^4aa=x^9$ now using $a^2=a^{-2}=e$ we have $x^4=x^9$ so $x^5=e$ and because $5$ is prime $x=e$ or $x$ has order $5$.

Comment: I don't understand how you got a^-1*x^6*a = x^9

Comment: @harry Multiplying by $x^3$ on the right member and by $a^{-1}x^2a$ on the left, which are equals.

Answer (score 4):

Since there is an answer up, I would do $$ax^2a=x^3$$

$$x^2=a^2x^2a^2=ax^3a=x^3axa$$

$$axa=x^{-1}$$

$$ax^2a=x^{-2}=x^3$$

Leaving you with some bits to fill in.

Comment: I'm confused. Your approach looks quite different from the answer above?

Comment: That's the beauty of maths!